# MapReduce using MongoDB Java Driver failes with wrong type for BSONElement assertion

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and MapReduce. I need to do some MapReduce on a collection in my DB. The `MAP` and `REDUCE_MAX` functions work, since I was able to accomplish my needs in the Mongo interactive shell (v.1.8.2). However, I get an error trying to perform the same thing using the Mongo Java Driver (v. 2.6.3)

My `MAP` and `REDUCE_MAX` functions look like this:

```
String MAP =
            "function(){" +
                    "if(this.type != \"checkin\"){return;}" +
                    "if(!this.venue && !this.venue.id){return;}" +
                    "emit({userId:this.userId, venueId:this.venue.id}, {count:1});" +
                    "};";


String REDUCE_MAX =
            "function(key, values){" +
                    "var res = {count:0};" +
                    "values.forEach(function(value){result.count += value.count;});" +
                    "return res;" +
                    "};";
```

This is the command I'm executing:

```
MapReduceOutput sum = collection
                .mapReduce(MAP, REDUCE_MAX, null, null);
```

This is the error I get:

```
com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command failed [command failed [mapreduce] { "assertion" : "wrong type for BSONElement (replace) 10 != 2" , "assertionCode" : 13111 , "errmsg" : "db assertion failure" , "ok" : 0.0}
```

I don't know which BSONElement has the wrong type. And I've already googled the `assertionCode: 13111`. I've also checked in the MongoDB log, but did not find any clues there.

Does anyone have an idea, what I could be missing/doing wrong? If you guys need more details, just let me know please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I stumbled upon my mistake and figured to share the solution here, just in case somebody encounters a similar problem.

The invocation of the `mapReduce` method was causing the problem:

```
MapReduceOutput sum = collection
                .mapReduce(MAP, REDUCE_MAX, null, null);
```

Have a look at the Javadoc for this method:

```
/**
 * performs a map reduce operation
 * Runs the command in REPLACE output mode (saves to named collection)
 *
 * @param map
 *            map function in javascript code
 * @param outputTarget
 *            optional - leave null if want to use temp collection
 * @param reduce
 *            reduce function in javascript code
 * @param query
 *            to match
 * @return
 * @throws MongoException
 * @dochub mapreduce
 */
```

It states that the command is executed using `REPLACE` as output mode and that if one wants a temporary collection, the `outputTarget` should be `null`.

Unfortunately though, the constructor`MapReduceCommand`, which is used in the `mapReduce` method, only allows the `outputTarget` to be nullable if the `OutputType` is set to `INLINE` (according to the Javadoc of `MapReduceCommand.getOutputTarget()`).

So all I had to do is to change the third parameter from `null` to some `String`, like so:

```
MapReduceOutput sum = collection
                .mapReduce(MAP, REDUCE_MAX, "tmp", null);
```

This was like the only parameter I had not played around with while trying to figure out why it didn't work. I hope somebody might find this helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to try:

```
MapReduceOutput sum = collection.mapReduce(MAP, REDUCE_MAX, null, 
                  OutputType.INLINE, null);
```

if you want to have an inline collection without giving it a name