# MongoDB map reduce, gives error " No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.Boolean to type int"

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

The code in Java I'm calling is..

```
  String reduceFunction="classpath:reduceJustCount.js";
  String mapFunction = "classpath:mapBreachesByModule.js";
  MapReduceResults<MapReduceValue> mapReduceResults = mongoTemplate.mapReduce(query, Collections.MONGO_COLLECTION, mapFunction, reduceFunction, MapReduceValue.class);
```

mapBreachesByModule.js

```
function () {
    emit(this.ModuleName, this.Breach);
}
```

reduceJustCount.js

```
function (key, values){
    return values.length;
}
```

I have one row in my Collection.

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "52efc24bc09559e531269e2c"} , "ModuleName" : "SystemParameterServiceRS" , "Breach" : false }
```

I get the following exception...

```
nested exception is org.springframework.c
ore.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.Boolean to type int] with root cause
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.Boolean to type int
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:475)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:673)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$100(MappingMongoConverter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:957)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:713)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:248)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:240)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1841)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.mapReduce(MongoTemplate.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.mapReduce(MongoTemplate.java:1080)
```

I know the field I'm "Mapping" is a boolean, but it should just total them up. I've changed my reduce function to be a simple as possible and I still get the problem.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most definitely with the types you are passing in and processing with your map and reduce phases. See the following two links which are much the same as the example you are giving:

http://hmkcode.com/mongodb-java-mapreduce/

[MapReduce using MongoDB Java Driver failes with wrong type for BSONElement assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306329/mapreduce-using-mongodb-java-driver-failes-with-wrong-type-for-bsonelement-asser)

Additionally, not sure what your goal here is but unless you really need MapReduce you might want to look at the [Aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). There is a lot that can be done there and it will generally be faster than the equivalent usign MapReduce

Additional resource for Java: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/